# Writing from python to an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I am new to Python and I am trying to write my data from python to an excel spreadsheet. This is my python output. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi9ic.jpg I want the timestamp data from the python output to be written to an excel spreadsheet in this format https://i.stack.imgur.com/urdGX.jpg but the problem is I have no idea how to extract all the data from the python output. For the boot timestamp, I am only able to extract a single data value. How do I extract all the values from the python output and write it to the excel spreadsheet?

This is my code:

```
import xlwt

pat1 = 'Boot 0x0100M'
pat2 = '2Sync:0 4'
pat3= '2Sync:1 C'
pat_no = 3
matchedline= ''
CE_count = 0
pattern_list = [pat1,pat2,pat3]

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding = 'utf-8')
sheet1 = book.addsheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)

sheet1.write(0,0,"spin)
sheet1.write(0,1,"start")
sheet1.write(0,2,"end")
count=0
for i in range(1,9,1):
 sheet1.write(i,0, count)
 count+=1

with open('C:\\Test_Automation\\spinup_spindown.txt') as file:
 for line in file:
  CE_count=1
  for pattern in pattern_list:
   if pattern in line:
    matchedline=line
    print(matchedline)
    timestamp1=matchedline[0:13]
    timestamp2=matchedline[0:13]
    timestamp3=matchedline[0:13]
    if pattern == pat1:
     print(timestamp1)
     sheet1.write(1,1,timestamp1)
    if pattern == pat2:
     print(timestamp2)
    if pattern == pat3:
     print(timestamp3)


book.save("C:\\Test_Automation\\trial.xls")
```

Comment: Your life would be a lot simpler if you output a `.csv` which you then import into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**
In the statement `sheet1.write(0,0,"spin#)` you have the pound symbol (#), which initiates a comment in python. This comments out the rest of your code, which is likely causing the errors.

In addition, I would recommend writing data to a CSV file, and then importing that into Excel, rather than directly writing into and Excel file. CSV files are easier to use for data manipulation and are supported by various python dataframe libraries, such as Pandas.

Comment: How do I write data to a CSV file and then import it into excel?

Comment: In Excel, you can go to the data tab and then in the Get & Transform Data section click From Text/CSV. I personally haven't scraped data from a txt to a csv, but there are multiple tutorials on how to do so. If you already have a txt file that has commas or other symbols separating different columns, you can import that directly without converting to CSV.